# C++11 Thread Pool

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

I've been using a thread pool that I wrote using Windows threads for a while and I've decided to update it to use `std::threads`.  I'm looking for some feedback on how this could be improved in terms of (in order of importance) reliability, usability, and performance.

Header

```
#pragma once

#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

namespace std
{
    class mutex;
    class condition_variable;
}//namespace std

namespace Utilities
{
    class Semaphore final
    {
    private:
        std::condition_variable* _condition;
        std::mutex*              _mutex;
        unsigned                 _count;

    public:
        Semaphore();
        ~Semaphore();

    public:
        void Wait();
        void Notify();
    };

    class Worker final
    {
    public:
        typedef std::function<void()> Task;

    private: 
        std::queue<Task> _tasks;
        std::thread*     _thread;
        std::mutex*      _mutex;
        Semaphore        _semaphore;
        bool             _alive;

    public:
        Worker();
        ~Worker();

    public:
        std::thread::id id        () const;
        size_t          task_count() const;

        void Join      (         ) const;
        void PushTask  (Task task);
        void ClearTasks(         );
    };

    class ThreadPool final
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Worker> _workers;
        unsigned            _index;

    public:
        ThreadPool(unsigned thread_count = 0);
        ~ThreadPool();

    public:
        unsigned thread_count();
        unsigned task_count  ();

        void Join      (                 );
        void PushTask  (Worker::Task task);
        void ClearTasks(                 );
    };
}//namespace Utilities
```

Source

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

#include <mutex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace Utilities;

Semaphore::Semaphore() :
    _condition(new std::condition_variable()),
    _mutex    (new std::mutex             ()),
    _count    (0                            )
{ }

Semaphore::~Semaphore()
{
    delete _condition;
    delete _mutex;
}

void Semaphore::Wait()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*_mutex);
    while (!_count)
        _condition->wait(lock);
    --_count;
}//Wait

void Semaphore::Notify()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*_mutex);
    _condition->notify_one();
    ++_count;
}//Notify

Worker::Worker() :
    _mutex(new std::mutex()),
    _alive(true            )
{
    _thread = new std::thread(
    [&]
    {
        while (_alive)
        {
            _semaphore.Wait();

            while (!_tasks.empty())
            {
                _mutex->lock();
                Task task = _tasks.front();
                _mutex->unlock();

                task();

                _mutex->lock();
                if (!_tasks.empty())
                    _tasks.pop();
                _mutex->unlock();
            }
        }
    });
}

Worker::~Worker()
{
    ClearTasks();
    _alive = false;
    _semaphore.Notify();

    _thread->join();

    delete _thread;
    delete _mutex;
}

std::thread::id Worker::id() const
{ return _thread->get_id(); }
//id

size_t Worker::task_count() const
{ return _tasks.size(); }
//task_count

void Worker::Join() const
{ while (_tasks.size()); }
//Join

void Worker::PushTask(Task task)
{
    _mutex->lock();
    _tasks.push(task);
    _mutex->unlock();

    _semaphore.Notify();
}//PushTask

void Worker::ClearTasks()
{
    _mutex->lock();
    _tasks = std::queue<Task>();
    _mutex->unlock();
}//ClearTasks

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(unsigned thread_count) :
    _index(0)
{
    if (!thread_count)
        thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    _workers = std::vector<Worker>(std::max(1u, thread_count));
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    ClearTasks();
    Join      ();
}

unsigned ThreadPool::thread_count()
{ return _workers.size(); }
//thread_count

unsigned ThreadPool::task_count()
{
    unsigned task_count = 0;
    for (auto& worker : _workers)
        task_count += worker.task_count();
    return task_count;
}//task_count

void ThreadPool::Join()
{ while (task_count()); }
//Join

void ThreadPool::PushTask(Worker::Task task)
{
    _workers[_index++].PushTask(task);
    if (_index >= _workers.size())
        _index = 0;
}//PushTask

void ThreadPool::ClearTasks()
{
    for (auto& worker : _workers)
        worker.ClearTasks();
}//ClearTasks
```

Usage Example

```
#include "ThreadPool.h"

#include <iostream>

static void Method_0(              ) { std::cout << "Method_0()" << std::endl; }
static void Method_1(float my_float) { std::cout << my_float     << std::endl; }
static void Method_2(int&  my_int  ) { my_int += my_int;                       }

struct Foo
{
           void Bar() { std::cout << "Foo::Bar() : Instance" << std::endl; }
    static void Baz() { std::cout << "Foo::Baz() : Static"   << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace Utilities;

    Foo foo;
    int my_int = 16;

    ThreadPool thread_pool;
    thread_pool.PushTask(Method_0);
    thread_pool.PushTask(std::bind(Method_1, 3.14f));
    thread_pool.PushTask(std::bind(Method_2, std::ref(my_int)));
    thread_pool.PushTask(std::bind(&Foo::Bar, foo));
    thread_pool.PushTask(&Foo::Baz);
    thread_pool.PushTask([]{ std::cout << "Lambda" << std::endl; });
    thread_pool.Join();

    std::cout << my_int << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Miscellaneous:

I imagine you did this:

```
namespace std
{
    class mutex;
    class condition_variable;
}//namespace std
```

To have a forward declaration of those types and avoid the `#includes`. I don't like this though. There is no guarantee that `mutex` or `condition_variable` are plain `class` types. They could be anything, structs, template classes, or even typedefs to anything else. So this is certainly not portable across compilers and might even break on a future update of your current compiler. Including the relevant files in the header is cleaner, safer and also simpler.

Also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290176/1198654).

---

The busy wait loop in `Worker::Join()` could take advantage of [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield), which might perform better than just spinning.

```
void Worker::Join() const
{ 
    while (_tasks.size())
    {
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}
```

---

Those comments at the end of every other method are plain noise.

> ```
> void ThreadPool::ClearTasks()
> {
>     for (auto& worker : _workers)
>         worker.ClearTasks();
> }//ClearTasks
> ```

Your methods are not that big, I can see where they begin and end very easily without that comment.

---

While not technically wrong in the context you've used, names starting with an underscore bare a few restrictions in C++. FYI, I suggest reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654).

---

#### Copy and assignment:

As it stands, your classes can be copied using `operator =` or the implicit copy constructor. Doing so would wreak havoc in your program, since each copy would be a shallow copy and multiple attempts to delete the same pointers would be done by the destructors of different objects. You should at the very least `delete` the copy constructor and assignment operator of `Semaphore` and `Worker`, and perhaps also from `Thread`. E.g.:

```
class Semaphore final
{
    Semaphore(const Semaphore &) = delete;
    Semaphore & operator = (const Semaphore &) = delete;
    // copy and assignment are now disallowed.
};
```

This falls into what is known as [*Rule of Three*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which means that if a construtor does some non-trivial work, such as memory allocation, then more than likely you'll need to define custom copy constructor and assignment as well (or disable them).

---

#### Memory Management:

In the `Semaphore` class, `condition_variable` and `mutex` are declared as pointers. I would declare them by value to avoid extra memory allocations and improve data locality. I don't see any obvious reason for them to be pointers. If you do keep the pointers and dynamic allocations, then consider using a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) rather than manual `new` and `delete` calls, to ensure exception safety and simplify the resource management logic. Same applies to `thread` and `mutex` in `Worker`. Those could be declared by value as well. Otherwise, would be better as smart pointers too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.I was not aware that mutex, and condition_variable are not guaranteed to be classes, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex shows it to be a class, but I can easily move the includes into the header.

I really don't like having thread, mutex, and condition_variable as raw pointers, but since they need to be contained in standard containers, I felt that raw pointers turned out to be the simplest solution in this case.

I will certainly look into std::this_thread::yield for Join().

Comment: @PatrickPurcell, Yes, that is a possible/reference interface, however, there is no standard way to forward declare anything inside the namespace std, besides including the relevant files. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10290176/1198654) asks precisely this, the single answer provided cites the C++11 standard.

Comment: @PatrickPurcell, I also forgot to mention the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). This is important. I'll update the answer now.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the SO question with the C++11 standard for forward declarations in the std namespace.  I will fix that as well as add copy constructors and copy assignment operators.

Comment: In this case would you prefer non-copyable over having a custom copy constructor and assignment operator, if so, why?

Comment: @PatrickPurcell, `Semaphore` and `Worker` could be made copyable, but then each copy would have to create their own new mutexes and threads, because those objects cannot themselves be copied. So you can only implement a partial copy for semaphore/worker. Unless you really see a necessity to make them copiable, then yes, I'd keep it simple and delete the operator/constructor.